# How to scale a PDF font size on a webpage for a print out?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

For a example, the font size of the PDF is so small that it isn't able to read when I took a print out. Could anybody know a workaround for this?

BTW I am using Chrome browser on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the font size in a PDF short of editing the PDF itself. This requires a PDF editing program such as Adobe Acrobat Pro.

You can try scaling the pages when you print the PDF, but this is mostly limited to making the PDF fit onto the paper you're printing on, and so to make it larger you'd have to be printing on larger paper.

Answer (score -2):

You might be able to affect the font size of the saved PDF by opening the developer console (Right-click, Inspect, or View/Developer/Developer Tools) and modifying the CSS directly.  You'll likely be looking for `font-size`, or similar, and the higher up the DOM the better.  If you don't see it you can add it directly under the `body` tag.  Try something like 200%, hit Print and see how it looks.